# Differences between vectors _including_ NA

Tags: r, vector, na

Suppose I have a vector `x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA)`.

I apply some mythological code to that vector, which results in another vector, `y<-c(1,NA,3, 4,10,NA)`

Now I wish to find out *at which positions* my two vectors differ, where I count two `NA`s as being the same, and one `NA` and a non-`NA` (e.g. the second element of the two example vectors).

Specifically, for my example, I would like to end up with a vector holding `c(2,3,5)`.

For my use case, I am not content with a vector of logical variables, but obviously I can easily convert (`which`), so I'll accept that as well.

I have some solutions like:

```
simplediff<-x!=y
nadiff<-is.na(x)!=is.na(y)
which(simplediff | nadiff)
```

but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel here. Any better options?

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @James: it's like that old cartoon w/ a bunch of horrific equations on the top of the blackboard, then the statement "next a miracle occurs" , followed by the desired final equation.

Comment: OK, who's been downvoting all the answers without even providing a comment as to why he doesn't like the answers?  Bad form.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That was like every maths lecture I had!

Answer (score 6):

How about looping and using `identical`?

```
 !mapply(identical,x,y)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

And for positions:

```
seq_along(x)[!mapply(identical,x,y)]
[1] 2 3 5
```

or

```
which(!mapply(identical,x,y))
[1] 2 3 5
```

Comment: Interesting but presumably overkill, since it will check differences in names and other attributes.  (Downvote wasn't me!)

Comment: @RichieCotton Good point, thought the options could fine tune that behaviour, but it seems it only makes it more strict.

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution (but sure it is not the best):

```
(1:length(x))[-which((x-y)==0)]
```

Comment: This has a few advantages (it doesn't work for character vectors, for example), but apart from that: if both original and new vector hold `NA` at some spot, this will mark this spot as different (I've edited my original question to include this in the example). Still, thanks for the effort.